# Resize images on a carousel

Tags: wordpress, image, resize, carousel

I am working on a wordpress site using the Morrison hotel theme.
This theme has a fairly large slider in the middle.
I find it far too tall in height.
However, when I decrease the height of the owl-carousel div for example, the size reduction is done well but the images are not resized. I end up with the top of the image. I guess the problem is that I want to keep my ful-width display but reduce the height...
Could you give me a hint to reduce the size in height of the slider and keep the right proportion of the photos?
I tried to give you a snippet here but otherwise the site address is https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/

```css
.owl-carousel {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  /* position relative and z-index fix webkit rendering fonts issue */
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.owl-carousel .owl-stage {
  position: relative;
  -ms-touch-action: pan-Y;
}

.owl-carousel .owl-stage:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.owl-carousel .owl-stage-outer {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* fix for flashing background */
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
}

.owl-carousel .owl-item {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
  float: left;
  /*-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;*/
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}

.owl-carousel .owl-item img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.owl-carousel .owl-nav.disabled,
.owl-carousel .owl-dots.disabled {
  display: none;
}

.owl-carousel .owl-nav .owl-prev,
.owl-carousel .owl-nav .owl-next,
.owl-carousel .owl-dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  cursor: hand;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.owl-carousel.owl-loaded {
  display: block;
}

.owl-carousel.owl-loading {
  opacity: 0;
  display: block;
}

.owl-carousel.owl-hidden {
  opacity: 0;
}

.owl-carousel.owl-refresh .owl-item {
  display: none;
}

.owl-carousel.owl-drag .owl-item {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.owl-carousel.owl-grab {
  cursor: move;
  cursor: -webkit-grab;
  cursor: grab;
}

.owl-carousel.owl-rtl {
  direction: rtl;
}

.owl-carousel.owl-rtl .owl-item {
  float: right;
}

.owl-carousel .owl-controls {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 2em;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 5;
}

.owl-carousel .owl-dots {
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}

.owl-carousel .owl-dots .owl-dot {
  display: inline-block;
  zoom: 1;
  *display: inline;
}

.owl-carousel .owl-dots .owl-dot span {
  width: 11px;
  height: 11px;
  margin: 5px 7px;
  background: #fff;
  display: block;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  transition-property: opacity, background-color;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.owl-carousel .owl-dots .owl-dot.active span,
.owl-carousel .owl-dots .owl-dot:hover span {
  background: #c19c78;
}

/* No Js */

.no-js .owl-carousel {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="page-carousel" wfd-id="76">
    <div class="owl-carousel morrison-hotel-carousel owl-theme owl-center owl-loaded" data-cols="2" data-center="true" wfd-id="77"> 
        <div class="owl-stage-outer" wfd-id="103">
            <div class="owl-stage" style="transition: all 0.25s ease 0s; width: 9100px; transform: translate3d(-7150px, 0px, 0px);" wfd-id="104"><div class="owl-item cloned" style="width: 650px; margin-right: 0px;" wfd-id="131"><div wfd-id="132">
                        <img src="https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20171012_145725-815x500.jpg" width="815" height="500" srcset="https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20171012_145725-815x500.jpg 815w, https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20171012_145725-1140x699.jpg 1140w, https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20171012_145725-480x294.jpg 480w, https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20171012_145725-320x196.jpg 320w" sizes="(max-width: 815px) 100vw, 815px" alt="">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="owl-item cloned" style="width: 650px; margin-right: 0px;" wfd-id="129"><div wfd-id="130">
                        <img src="https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/DSCF2250-815x500.jpg" width="815" height="500" srcset="https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/DSCF2250-815x500.jpg 815w, https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/DSCF2250-1140x699.jpg 1140w, https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/DSCF2250-480x294.jpg 480w, https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/DSCF2250-320x196.jpg 320w" sizes="(max-width: 815px) 100vw, 815px" alt="">
                    </div>
                </div><div class="owl-item" style="width: 650px; margin-right: 0px;" wfd-id="127"><div wfd-id="128">
                        <img src="https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20180622_103809-815x500.jpg" width="815" height="500" srcset="https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20180622_103809-815x500.jpg 815w, https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20180622_103809-1140x699.jpg 1140w, https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20180622_103809-480x294.jpg 480w, https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20180622_103809-320x196.jpg 320w" sizes="(max-width: 815px) 100vw, 815px" alt="">
                    </div></div><div class="owl-item" style="width: 650px; margin-right: 0px;" wfd-id="125"><div wfd-id="126">
                        <img src="https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20180622_104005-815x500.jpg" width="815" height="500" srcset="https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20180622_104005-815x500.jpg 815w, https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20180622_104005-1140x699.jpg 1140w, https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20180622_104005-480x294.jpg 480w, https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20180622_104005-320x196.jpg 320w" sizes="(max-width: 815px) 100vw, 815px" alt="">
                    </div></div><div class="owl-item" style="width: 650px; margin-right: 0px;" wfd-id="123"><div wfd-id="124">
                        <img src="https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20180325_111721-815x500.jpg" width="815" height="500" srcset="https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20180325_111721-815x500.jpg 815w, https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20180325_111721-1140x699.jpg 1140w, https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20180325_111721-480x294.jpg 480w, https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20180325_111721-320x196.jpg 320w" sizes="(max-width: 815px) 100vw, 815px" alt="">
                    </div></div><div class="owl-item" style="width: 650px; margin-right: 0px;" wfd-id="121"><div wfd-id="122">
                        <img src="https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20180623_092543-815x500.jpg" width="815" height="500" srcset="https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20180623_092543-815x500.jpg 815w, https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20180623_092543-1140x699.jpg 1140w, https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20180623_092543-480x294.jpg 480w, https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20180623_092543-320x196.jpg 320w" sizes="(max-width: 815px) 100vw, 815px" alt="">
                    </div></div><div class="owl-item" style="width: 650px; margin-right: 0px;" wfd-id="119"><div wfd-id="120">
                        <img src="https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20180622_142800-815x500.jpg" width="815" height="500" srcset="https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20180622_142800-815x500.jpg 815w, https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20180622_142800-1140x699.jpg 1140w, https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20180622_142800-480x294.jpg 480w, https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20180622_142800-320x196.jpg 320w" sizes="(max-width: 815px) 100vw, 815px" alt="">
                    </div></div><div class="owl-item" style="width: 650px; margin-right: 0px;" wfd-id="117"><div wfd-id="118">
                        <img src="https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/DSCF2250-1-815x500.jpg" width="815" height="500" srcset="https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/DSCF2250-1-815x500.jpg 815w, https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/DSCF2250-1-1140x699.jpg 1140w, https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/DSCF2250-1-480x294.jpg 480w, https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/DSCF2250-1-320x196.jpg 320w" sizes="(max-width: 815px) 100vw, 815px" alt="">
                    </div></div><div class="owl-item" style="width: 650px; margin-right: 0px;" wfd-id="115"><div wfd-id="116">
                        <img src="https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20180622_103255-815x500.jpg" width="815" height="500" srcset="https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20180622_103255-815x500.jpg 815w, https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20180622_103255-1140x699.jpg 1140w, https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20180622_103255-480x294.jpg 480w, https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20180622_103255-320x196.jpg 320w" sizes="(max-width: 815px) 100vw, 815px" alt="">
                    </div></div><div class="owl-item" style="width: 650px; margin-right: 0px;" wfd-id="113"><div wfd-id="114">
                        <img src="https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20171012_151156-815x500.jpg" width="815" height="500" srcset="https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20171012_151156-815x500.jpg 815w, https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20171012_151156-1140x699.jpg 1140w, https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20171012_151156-480x294.jpg 480w, https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20171012_151156-320x196.jpg 320w" sizes="(max-width: 815px) 100vw, 815px" alt="">
                    </div></div><div class="owl-item" style="width: 650px; margin-right: 0px;" wfd-id="111"><div wfd-id="112">
                        <img src="https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20171012_145725-815x500.jpg" width="815" height="500" srcset="https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20171012_145725-815x500.jpg 815w, https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20171012_145725-1140x699.jpg 1140w, https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20171012_145725-480x294.jpg 480w, https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20171012_145725-320x196.jpg 320w" sizes="(max-width: 815px) 100vw, 815px" alt="">
                    </div></div><div class="owl-item active center" style="width: 650px; margin-right: 0px;" wfd-id="109"><div wfd-id="110">
                        <img src="https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/DSCF2250-815x500.jpg" width="815" height="500" srcset="https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/DSCF2250-815x500.jpg 815w, https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/DSCF2250-1140x699.jpg 1140w, https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/DSCF2250-480x294.jpg 480w, https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/DSCF2250-320x196.jpg 320w" sizes="(max-width: 815px) 100vw, 815px" alt="">
                    </div></div><div class="owl-item cloned" style="width: 650px; margin-right: 0px;" wfd-id="107"><div wfd-id="108">
                        <img src="https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20180622_103809-815x500.jpg" width="815" height="500" srcset="https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20180622_103809-815x500.jpg 815w, https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20180622_103809-1140x699.jpg 1140w, https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20180622_103809-480x294.jpg 480w, https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20180622_103809-320x196.jpg 320w" sizes="(max-width: 815px) 100vw, 815px" alt="">
                    </div></div><div class="owl-item cloned" style="width: 650px; margin-right: 0px;" wfd-id="105"><div wfd-id="106">
                        <img src="https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20180622_104005-815x500.jpg" width="815" height="500" srcset="https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20180622_104005-815x500.jpg 815w, https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20180622_104005-1140x699.jpg 1140w, https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20180622_104005-480x294.jpg 480w, https://hotel-restaurant-la-borie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/20180622_104005-320x196.jpg 320w" sizes="(max-width: 815px) 100vw, 815px" alt="">
                    </div></div></div></div><div class="owl-controls" wfd-id="78"><div class="owl-nav" wfd-id="100"><div class="owl-prev" style="display: none;" wfd-id="102">prev</div><div class="owl-next" style="display: none;" wfd-id="101">next</div></div><div class="owl-dots" style="" wfd-id="79"><div class="owl-dot" wfd-id="98"><span wfd-id="99"></span></div><div class="owl-dot" wfd-id="96"><span wfd-id="97"></span></div><div class="owl-dot" wfd-id="94"><span wfd-id="95"></span></div><div class="owl-dot" wfd-id="92"><span wfd-id="93"></span></div><div class="owl-dot" wfd-id="90"><span wfd-id="91"></span></div><div class="owl-dot" wfd-id="88"><span wfd-id="89"></span></div><div class="owl-dot" wfd-id="86"><span wfd-id="87"></span></div><div class="owl-dot" wfd-id="84"><span wfd-id="85"></span></div><div class="owl-dot" wfd-id="82"><span wfd-id="83"></span></div><div class="owl-dot active" wfd-id="80"><span wfd-id="81"></span></div></div></div></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the below CSS, change to whatever proportions you require

```
#page-carousel{
height:300px !important;
overflow:hidden !important; 
}

img{
height:100% !important;
}
```

Comment: I tried adding this style but it still cuts the image, I don't have the bottom of the image. It is not resized. do i have to impose a height: 500px on all divs? Even doing so the image is cut off, the bottom is missing.

Comment: After adding the above CSS the DIV with ID "page-carousel" should have a height of 300px and all Images should have a height equal to their parent container i.e. 300px. What height are you now getting for the DIV with ID "page-carousel" ? What height are you now getting for the images ?

Comment: Finally, i used #page-carousel img {max-height:600px; object-fit: cover; }

Comment: Your images had a height of 500px originally and you said you wanted to make them smaller. Specifying a max-height of 600px would not make them smaller

Comment: there was 815px of height. I wanted to reduce it.

Comment: no the image heights were set to 500px originally, the image width were 815px. If you read the code in your original question you can clearly see this.